# React Native : How to call a function only after sending last message on the chat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Use Case: on my chat app, I would like to send notification to other user/s only when the first user sends his/her last message.

Problem: I can always use the setTimeout method, but this seems a hack.

Is there a preferred way to achieve the ideal solution in this scenario?

```
Functions:


Send_Message_to_Server{
  // This function send a message from user to the server
}

Send_Notification(){
 // This function sends the push notification to other user

}

I want to call Send_Notification function inside Send_Message_to_Server only when user sends his/her last message.
```

Comment: I think you need to think about what the definition of a "last message" is without being able to see the future. Are you gonna predict if the user is done?

Comment: I do recommend you to read about `debouncing` pattern (lodash provides an implementation)